# GitHub search - how to exclude (logical NOT) company or user from search results

Tags: search, github, logical-operators, pull-request

[image]

In this search query ([test it live ↗](https://github.com/pulls?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Apr%20author%3Alimonte%20user%3Avaadin%20)) I'm searching for:

- all `pull requests`
- by user `limonte` (me)
- for the `vaadin` company

How can I search for all my pull requests **except** (logical NOT) those for `vaadin` company?

---

These two options I tried without success:

- `is:pr author:limonte user:!vaadin`
- `is:pr author:limonte user:NOT vaadin`

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Prefixing any search qualifier with a - excludes all results that are matched by that qualifier.

For example, you might be interested in finding all "cats" repositories with more than 10 stars that are not written in JavaScript:

```
cats stars:>10 -language:javascript
```

You might also want to find all issues mentioning @defunkt that are not in repositories in the GitHub organization:

```
mentions:defunkt -user:github
```

---

The answer for your question is:

> [is:pr author:limonte -user:vaadin](https://github.com/pulls?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Apr+author%3Alimonte+-user%3Avaadin+)

---

For more refer the [GitHub Search Syntax](https://help.github.com/articles/search-syntax/#filter-qualifiers-based-on-exclusion)

Comment: @NilayVishwakarma how can I negate with repository name, any idea on this?

Comment: @Shiv try something like this: `is:pr author:limonte -repo:sweetalert2/sweetalert2 `

Comment: @NilayVishwakarma yep it works
but in the above, we end up giving the `org/repo-name` or `user/repo-name` to exclude the result

any possible way that I can remove just based on repo-name, without passing the organisation or user?
something like
`-repo:jquery` to remove to all repo's with the name jquery

Comment: I don't think GitHub supports this.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in the notification search yet :(

Answer (score 38):

##### Use "NOT" for excluding words when searching a whole repository.

> `hello NOT world` matches repositories that have the word "hello" but
> not the word "world."

I got tired of getting unit tests in my searches, so I was searching like so:

```
NOT test in:path AND "search-term" in:file
```

##### Use "-QUALIFIER" for excluding results with a specific qualifier.

> `cats stars:>10 -language:javascript` matches repositories with the word "cats" that have more than 10 stars but are not written in JavaScript.

---

Quotes from:
https://docs.github.com/en/search-github/getting-started-with-searching-on-github/understanding-the-search-syntax#exclude-certain-results

Archived:
https://web.archive.org/web/20221014142718/https://docs.github.com/en/search-github/getting-started-with-searching-on-github/understanding-the-search-syntax#exclude-certain-results

Comment: Thank you! I needed to search for term "search" but exclude "replace" to find issues about "search" functionality (and NOT "search & replace" functionality).

Comment: Attention: GitHub is case-sensitive in this case, `NOT` has to be uppercase.

Comment: `NOT test in:path AND "abc" in:file` presents a `Code Search could not process your request, please try different search criteria.` It seems you cant combine flags. Doing "abc" in:file -test` worked though, but it might exclude more than intended. oh well.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore

Answer (score 10):

I think this would be helpful for everyone who gets confused between different ways of narrowing down the results:

---

### Use `NOT` for words

If you're trying to exclude a certain word, you should use `NOT` keyword before that.

In my case, I was trying to find microservice projects (not frameworks) written in Go.

`microservice NOT framework language:Go`

`microservice NOT framework NOT library language:Go`

including white space:

`cats NOT "hello world"`

---

### Use `-` for qualifiers

If you're trying to exclude specific qualifiers you should use `-`:

`cats stars:>10 -language:javascript` => any language except javascript

`mentions:defunkt -org:github` => any organization except github

---

Source: https://docs.github.com/en/search-github/getting-started-with-searching-on-github