# Search a github project, but avoid "test" directories?

Tags: node.js, github, search

Is there any way to exclude certain directories when searching a particular github project?

In a large project on Github like [nodejs](https://github.com/nodejs/node), I often want to search the source code to find where in the project something is defined.  A challenge I regularly run into is that the project itself contains hundreds of files related to module tests and these test directories clog up the search results when I'm trying to find something in the actual source, not in the testing code.  So, instead of getting 5 pages of results to look through, I might get 50 pages of results, rendering the search somewhat useless.

In the nodejs project, I'd like to search without including the top level "test" directory.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To search in one particular directory you can use:

```
searchterm path:/lib
```

And to ignore a directory you can use:

```
searchterm -path:/test
```

As mentioned in your comment, the official documentation is [here](https://help.github.com/en/github/searching-for-information-on-github/searching-code#search-by-file-location). An answer on how to ignore stuff can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43201579/github-search-how-to-exclude-logical-not-company-or-user-from-search-results).

Comment: How do you exclude with wildcards? For instance everything in a test directory not necessarily at the root of a project

Comment: They cannot be used as part of the search query [github help code search](https://docs.github.com/en/search-github/searching-on-github/searching-code#considerations-for-code-search) "You can't use the following wildcard characters as part of your search query: `. , : ; / \ \` ' " = * ! ? # $ & + ^ | ~ < > ( ) { } [ ] @`. The search will simply ignore these symbols"